# Name of this font that is shown in the image

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

[image]

I really need to get the name of this font .I had tried to find the name of this font using some of the sites like http://whatfontis.com/ and http://www.myfonts.com but couldn't succeed.So Can any one please help to find this font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I found this one but the A is diferent, it could be a modification? i hope this helps

http://www.fonts.com/font/fontfabric-type-foundry/intro-rust

Comment: can u name the font please because i couldn't get the name

Comment: @Sumann "Intro Rust" is the name.